# Receive events from C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, unity-game-engine, native

I know of the [Native Plugin Interface](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html) but I don't see how to **receive** an event from a C++ native plugin.

What I need to do is have my C++ native dll ping Unity when it finishes some work (and have Unity execute something reactively).

How can I accomplish this?

(I'm tagging this both C++ - the plugin and C# - the unity scripts I'm using, since I need both end to communicate)

Comment: You'll want to use some form of IPC to communicate between components. Try checking this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064103/interprocess-communication-between-c-sharp-and-c

Comment: Have you looked here? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: You need to do this separately for every platform. For iOS this is accomplished with [UnitySendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). Android seems to work similarly s. [forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-plugin-call-c-from-java.78598/)